# Find a set of variables for which an specific expression evaluates to true

Tags: boolean-algebra, disjunctive-normal-form

**Description.**
I have $m \in \mathbb N$ and three possible logical expressions, which I immediately presented in the most convenient notation:

1. $X \to Y = \lnot X \lor Y$
2. $X \to \lnot Y = \lnot X \lor \lnot Y$
3. $X \lor Y$

Let's agree to call logical components $X$ or $Y$ just *components*. They can take any value from the set $\{X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_m\}$, where $X_i \in \{0, 1\}$.

The above logical expressions can be combined with each other using the conjunction. **It is input expression**. For example, for $m=3$ we can have an expression like this
$(\lnot X_1 \lor X_2) \land (\lnot X_2 \lor \lnot X_3) \land (X_1 \lor X_3)$. But each boolean expression is optional. That is, there can be an expression of this kind $(\lnot X_1 \lor X_2) \land (X_1 \lor X_3)$

**Problem.** I have input expression which is described above. It is necessary to determine whether such a set $\{X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_m\}$ exists for any $m$ for which the input expression takes the value $1$.

For example, there is no answer for the input expression $(\lnot X_1 \lor X_3) \land (\lnot X_2 \lor X_1) \land (\lnot X_3 \lor \lnot X_1) \land (X_1 \lor X_2) = X_1 \land \lnot X_1 \neq 1$.

**My idea.** I use gluing for convert the input expression to disjunctive normal form. It works well. But I don't understand what to do next, because sometimes disjunctive normal form is more difficult than $X_1 \land \lnot X_1$. For example like here $(\lnot X_3 \lor X_2) \land (X_1 \lor X_2)$. It's not difficult to calculate this with your hands, but I need to program an algorithm.

Comment: Do you need the algorithm to have low time-complexity? If not, you can try all possible combinations of values for the $X_i$ until one combination works. For example, if $m=2$, you have 4 possibilities for $(X_1,X_2)$ which are $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$.

Comment: @cookiesandmilk Enumeration of all values ​​will not work, there is a time limit

Comment: Converting the input expression to DNF (disjunctive normal form) will take too much time for large $m$ because the result may have $2^m$ terms. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_to_DNF

Comment: The problem is described in [Wikipedia][1], and three algorithms to solve it are given.

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability

Comment: @cookiesandmilk Really. Did not know. Thank you!